# How to measure the amount of memory consumed by the stack?

Tags: debugging, stack, trace32, lauterbach, autosar

With Lauterbach TRACE32, how to measure the amount of memory consumed by the stack when the application is running?

I am using AUTOSAR OS on a PowerPC CPU.

Comment: Do you use an operating system on your target? Which CPU architecture are you using?

Comment: @Holger I am using a multi core PowerPC SoC, with AUTOSAR running on the main core and no RTOS on the slave core.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case you'd like to know the memory consumed by the **stacks of the tasks** I think the easiest way is to consult window `TASK.STacK.view`. 
Ensure the following to get `TASK.STacK.view` working

- Set-up the debuggers OS awareness (after loading your ELF), with `TASK.ORTI` for AUTOSAR or `TASK.CONFIG` for any other target OS.
- Initialize the stacks of your task with a magic pattern, which can be done in the start code of your OS or with TRACE32 `Data.Set` command.
- Possibly declare the magic initialization pattern to the debugger with command `TASK.STacK.PATtern`, if not detected by the OS awareness.

---

In case you'd like to know the memory consumed by the stack of a **bare-metal application** you have to check this via a PRACTICE script.

The basic idea here is to initialize the stack with a fixed pattern (before the application starts) and than check later which percentage of the stack does not longer contain the initialization pattern.

You can do this in the following three steps:

1st initialize your stack with a magic pattern after loading your ELF like this (or do this in the start-up code of your application):

```
GLOBAL &lowAddr &highAddr &magicPattern
&lowAddr=ADDRESS.OFFSET(__stack_start)   // assign here the upper border of the addressrange occupied by your stack
&highAddr=ADDRESS.OFFSET(__stack_end)-1  // assign here the lower border of the addressrange occupied by your stack 
&magicPattern=0xCCCCCCCC   // any 32-bit you like which appears unlikely on the used part of the stack 
Data.Set &lowAddr--&highAddr %Long &magicPattern   // initialize the stack
```

Secondly create a script (stackcheck.cmm) to check the stack usage like this:

```
PRIVATE &lowAddr &highAddr &pattern &addr
ENTRY   &lowAddr &highAddr &pattern

IF ("&lowAddr"=="")||("&highAddr"=="")||("&pattern "=="")
(
    PRINT %ERROR "At least one of the 3 required parameters is missing"
    ENDDO
)
VAR.NEWGLOBAL int \stacksize=0
VAR.NEWGLOBAL int \stackusage=0

&addr=&lowAddr   
WHILE (Data.LONG(D:&addr)==&pattern)&&(&addr<&highAddr)
    &addr=&addr+4

Var.Set %SPaces \stacksize = (&highAddr - &lowAddr) + 1
Var.Set %SPaces \stackusage = (&highAddr - &addr) + 1
Var.View \stacksize \stackusage (100*\stackusage)/\stacksize    // Show result
ENDDO
```

(You might want to optimize the way to search through the address-range of the stack.)

Finally call the script to detect the current stack usage like this:

```
DO stackcheck.cmm &lowAddr &highAddr &magicPattern
```

If you want to check the stack-usage pretty often you might want to use `MENU.AddTool` to create a button for this in the tool-bar of TRACE32.

Comment: I am getting a `symbol not found` error in line `B::&highAddr=ADDRESS.OFFSET(__stack_end)-1`.

Comment: Sergey, you have to assign to &highAddr the upper address occupied by your stack. This address is usually assigned to a symbol in your applications linker script. In my example I had a debug symbol called __stack_end which points to this address. In case you have an ELF section called ".stack" for your stack than the lines would be `&highAddr=ADDRESS.OFFSET(sYmbol.SECEND(.stack))` and `&lowAddr=ADDRESS.OFFSET(sYmbol.SECADDRESS(.stack))`. So the two lines initializing &lowAddr and &highAddr must be set by yourself to the borders of your application's stack.

Comment: In this case it should be `&lowAddr=ADDRESS.OFFSET(__SP_INIT)-0x10000` and `&highAddr=ADDRESS.OFFSET(__SP_INIT)-1`

Comment: In this case you've called the script stackcheck.cmm with command `DO` with empty arguments. Check `PMACRO` window, if you're global macros declared in the first step have been deleted. Or declare `&lowAddr &highAddr &magicPattern` again before calling stackcheck.cmm. Or assign the values directly inside stackcheck.cmm.

Comment: I have the feeling that you are not very familiar with PRACTICE scripts. I recommend to download at least the [PRACTICE reference card](http://www.lauterbach.com/reference_card_web.pdf) and maybe you should also read the training manual for the Script Language PRACTICE (http://www.lauterbach.com/pdfnew/training_practice.pdf).

Comment: For starters, call the script instead of with `DO` with `PSTEP`, which allows you to single step through the script. Open `PMACRO`window to watch the macros used in the script.